# Cannot access site to admin after disabling cache

Tags: magento-1.9, error, extensions, cache, captcha

I was attempting to install a Google Captcha extension from MageComp. In the install instructions it said: 
" It’s required to disable cache in the administration panel of your site. Go to System/Cache Management.  Choose all caches and take action “Disable” then submit. "

As soon as I did this I was presented with the following error screen: 
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: `693155652642`

Now  I cannot access either the website or the admin area, I just get the error screen. I  tried editing the database to re-enable the Cache, however it made no difference. I should have backed up the site before I did this, but thought it would be a simple install, & that nothing would go wrong (big mistake). Below is a copy of the 'Error log record number: 693155652642' Does anybody have any idea?

```
a:4:{i:0;s:98:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'selbergf_magento'@'localhost' (using password: YES)";i:1;s:2317:"#0 /home/selbergf/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/selbergf/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(251): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/selbergf/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(448): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/selbergf/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /home/selbergf/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(333): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/selbergf/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Type/Db/Pdo/Mysql.php(45): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /home/selbergf/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(93): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Type_Db_Pdo_Mysql->getConnection(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /home/selbergf/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_read')
#8 /home/selbergf/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(312): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->_getConnection('read')
#9 /home/selbergf/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Cache.php(41): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#10 /home/selbergf/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(424): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Cache->getAllOptions()
#11 /home/selbergf/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(459): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#12 /home/selbergf/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1101): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#13 /home/selbergf/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(404): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#14 /home/selbergf/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(286): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#15 /home/selbergf/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(359): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#16 /home/selbergf/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(295): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#17 /home/selbergf/public_html/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /home/selbergf/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Comment: Try to check with disable the extension.

Comment: you have also incorrect database password see **Access denied for user 'selbergf_magento'@'localhost' (using password: YES)** correct it first

Answer (score 1):

Open up `app/etc/local.xml` and make sure the database password is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The cause can be one of the following:

- MySQL password is incorrect, update `app/etc/local.xml`
- `localhost` may not work, change it to `127.0.0.1` in
  `app/etc/local.xml`
- Disabling your cache could have overwhelmed the MySQL database and it stopped, try restarting it
- Clear your `var/cache` and/or `var/full_page_cache`